# Python Pandas - Main DataFrame, want to drop all columns in smaller DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame ('main') that has about 300 columns.  I created a smaller DataFrame ('public') and have been working on this.

I now want to delete the columns contained within 'public' from the larger DataFrame ('main').

I've tried the following instructions:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

[Python Pandas - Deleting multiple series from a data frame in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363640/python-pandas-deleting-multiple-series-from-a-data-frame-in-one-command)

without any success, along with various other statements that have been unsuccessful.

The columns that make up 'public' are not consecutive - i.e. they are taken from various points in the larger DataFrame 'main'.  All of the columns have the same Index. [Not sure if this is important, but 'public' was created using the 'join' function].

Yes, I'm being lazy - I don't want to have to type out the names of every column!  I'm hoping there's a way to use the DataFrame 'public' in a statement that will allow deletion of these columns en masse.  If anyone has any suggestions and/or guidance I'd be most grateful.

(Have Python 2.7 and am using Pandas, numpy, math, pylab etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore my question - Murphy's Law prevails and I've just solved it.

I was using the statement from the stackoverflow question mentioned below:

```
df.drop(df.columns[1:], axis=1)
```

and this was not working.  I have instead used

```
df = df.drop(df2, axis=1)
```

and this worked (df = main, df2 = public).  Simple really once you don't overthink it.