# Dropping Multiple Columns from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know how to drop columns from a data frame using Python. But for my problem the data set is vast, the columns I want to drop are grouped together or are basically singularly spread out across the column heading axis. Is there a shorter way to slice or drop all the columns with fewer lines of code rather than to write it out like how I have done. The way I have done it here works but I would like a more summarized way.

The flight_data_copy_final is the variable in which it should be stored.

Here's my code:

```
from IPython.display import display

flight_data_copy_version1 = flight_data_copy.drop(flight_data_copy.ix[:,"Year": "FlightDate"].columns, axis=1)
flight_data_copy_version2 = flight_data_copy_version1.drop("TailNum", axis=1)
flight_data_copy_version3 = flight_data_copy_version2.drop("OriginStateFips", axis=1)
flight_data_copy_version4 = flight_data_copy_version3.drop("DestStateFips", axis=1)
flight_data_copy_version5 = flight_data_copy_version4.drop("Diverted", axis=1)
flight_data_copy_version6 = flight_data_copy_version5.drop("Flights", axis=1)
flight_data_copy_final = flight_data_copy.drop(flight_data_copy_version6.ix[:,"FirstDepTime":].columns, axis=1)

print (display (flight_data_copy_final))
```

Comment: you can do it this way: `df.drop(['col1','col2','col5','colN'], 1)`

Comment: You don't need to assign so many intermediate variables. You could do `df.drop('col1', axis=1).drop('col2', axis=1)....`. Or better drop all cols in one operation, and possibly inplace with `df.drop(['col1','col2','col5','colN'], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To delete multiple columns at the same time in pandas, you could specify the column names as shown below. The option  `inplace=True` is needed if one wants the change affected column in the same dataframe. Otherwise remove it.

```
flight_data_copy.drop(['TailNum', 'OriginStateFips', 
                'DestStateFips', 'Diverted'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Source: [Python Pandas - Deleting multiple series from a data frame in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363640/python-pandas-deleting-multiple-series-from-a-data-frame-in-one-command)

Answer (score 21):

```
    df.drop(columns=['col_1', 'col_2','col_N'])
```

[image: In my case, I solve it like thisenter image description here]

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the accepted answer?

Comment: I like this answer, the code is more readable using `columns=` instead of `axis=1`. I think both are equivalent though.

Comment: The accepted answer gave me errors when I used it with a list of column names - this small change doesn't give an error